# On Qubes OS 4.0, how to get xl console access to sys-net?

Tags: console, xen, serial-console, qubes, virtual-consoles

I tried `xl console sys-net` which is something that works for any other VM (AppVM, TemplateVM), it even works for `sys-net-dm` (I don't know what that is though)

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ time sudo xl console sys-net
xenconsole: Could not read tty from store: No such file or directory

real    0m5.036s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.015s


[ctor@dom0 ~]$ rpm -qf `which xl`
xen-runtime-4.8.4-2.fc25.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unknown reasons (bug?) you have to explicitly use the `-t` flag to specify the console type, which can be any of the two `serial` of `pv`. Either works!

So either of the following two work:
`sudo xl console -t pv sys-net`
`sudo xl console -t serial sys-net`
But this won't work for `sys-net`:
`sudo xl console sys-net`

```
$ xl console --help
Usage: xl [-v] console [options] <Domain>
-t <type>       console type, pv or serial
-n <number>     console number

Attach to domain's console.

[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo xl console -t pv sys-net 

Fedora 28 (Twenty Eight)
Kernel 4.14.67-1.pvops.qubes.x86_64 on an x86_64 (hvc0)

sys-net login:

[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo xl console -t serial sys-net 

Fedora 28 (Twenty Eight)
Kernel 4.14.67-1.pvops.qubes.x86_64 on an x86_64 (hvc0)

sys-net login: 

[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo xl console sys-net 
xenconsole: Could not read tty from store: No such file or directory

[ctor@dom0 ~]$ rpm -qf `which xl`
xen-runtime-4.8.4-2.fc25.x86_64
```

Note: Exit console by pressing `Ctrl+]`

`sys-net` has Virtualization mode set to `HVM`. All the other VMs have it set to `default (PVH)`. That seems to be the main difference.